# How to display only the second item from XML with this PHP script?

Tags: php, xml

How to display only the second item from XML with this PHP script?

```
<xml>
    <item>
        <name>Examplename</name>
        <amount>0000</amount>
    </item>
    <item>
        <name>Examplename</name>
        <amount>0000</amount>
    </item>
    <item>
        <name>Examplename</name>
        <amount >0000</amount>
    </item>
    <item>
        <name>DExamplename</name>
        <amount>0000</amount>
    </item>
</xml>


<?

// DOMElement->getElementsByTagName() -- Gets elements by tagname
// nodeValue : The value of this node, depending on its type.
// Load XML File. You can use loadXML if you wish to load XML data from a string

$objDOM = new DOMDocument();
$objDOM->load("feed.xml"); //make sure path is correct


$note = $objDOM->getElementsByTagName("item");

// for each note tag, parse the document and get values for
// tasks and details tag.

foreach( $note as $value ){


$places = $value->getElementsByTagName("name");
$place  = $places->item(0)->nodeValue;

$details = $value->getElementsByTagName("amount");
$detail  = $details->item(0)->nodeValue;




echo "<BODY STYLE='background-color:transparent'>

<table border='0'>
  <tr>
    <td width='127'><table width='127px' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
<tr>
<td><p style='font-family:arial;color:white;font-size:22px;padding-left:3px;text-align:left;  background:url(bg2.png)'><strong> $place</strong></p></td>

</tr>

</table>
</td>
    <td width='115'>
      <table width='115px' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
        <tr>
          <td><p style='font-family:arial;color:white;font-size:22px;text-align:right;padding-right:5px; background:url(bg1.png)'><strong>$detail</strong></p></td>

        </tr>

</table></td>
  </tr>

</table>




";
 $i++; }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to exploit [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp)

Using [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php):

```
<?php
$str = <<<STR
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<XmlDoc>
    <item>
        text
    </item>
    <item>
        text2
    </item>
</XmlDoc>
STR;
$xml = simplexml_load_string($str);
$second_item = $xml->xpath('//item[2]'); // notice [2]!
var_export($second_item);
```

Using [DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and [DOMXPath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php):

```
<?php
$str = <<<STR
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xml>
    <item>
        <name>Examplename</name>
        <amount>0000</amount>
    </item>
    <item>
        <name>Examplename</name>
        <amount>0000</amount>
    </item>
    <item>
        <name>Examplename</name>
        <amount >0000</amount>
    </item>
    <item>
        <name>DExamplename</name>
        <amount>0000</amount>
    </item>
</xml>
STR;

$xml = DOMDocument::loadXML($str);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($xml);
$x = $xpath->query('//item[2]');
var_export($x->item(0)->nodeValue);
```

Comment: I can't modify the XML file though, it's hosted by someone else, and alot other sites use the feed. Any other suggestions? Thanks for help btw.

Comment: You don't need to modify the XML. You just load it with SimpleXML or DOCDocument.

Comment: I got the required line to be shown, everything works fine, thanks. But how do i make it so that i dont have to enter the XML data by myself but that it is inserted from the original feed? I went the SimpleXML way.